# replace the carriage space

Tags: sql, oracle

How to remove the carriage space using SQL query. I tried the replace (..) idea but its not working at all ? The duplicate idea is not working

Comment: Please show an example of your data and what you have tried so far.

Comment: What exactly did you try? Please add this to the question

Comment: I tried 'select replace (col, chr(13),'x') from table_nm; Its not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle REPLACE() function isn't handling carriage-returns & line-feeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407027/oracle-replace-function-isnt-handling-carriage-returns-line-feeds)

Comment: No that idea is not working

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407135/oracle-regexp-to-replace-n-r-and-t-with-space

Comment: You keep saying various solutions aren't working. I think you should post some sample of the text you are trying to amend; include a DUMP() output of the string so we can see the non-printing characters as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should go with below code -

```
REPLACE(REPLACE( col_name, CHR(10)), CHR(13))
```

This will replace the spaces and carriage both and might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I generally use the test1 option:

```
select  replace(replace('teste 
        return test', chr (13), ''), chr (10), ' ') test1,

        translate('teste 
        return test', chr(10) || chr(13) || chr(09), ' ') test2
from dual;
```