# How to count length of line break as 2 characters in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data stored in table's column and it has a line break in the data. When I count the length of the string it returns me the count just fine. I want to make some changes and take the line break as 2 characters so if the data in table is something like this.

```
This
That
```

This should return length as 10 instead it is returning 9 for now which is understandable but I was to count the length of line break as 2 characters. So if there are 2 line breaks in data it will count them as 4 characters.

How can I achieve this ?

I want to use this in `SUBSTR(COL, 1, 7)`
By counting line break as 2 character it should return data like this

```
This
T
```

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 0):

Just replace new line in the string with 2 characters, for example 'xx', before counting string length. More info on how to replace new lines in Oracle: [Oracle REPLACE() function isn't handling carriage-returns & line-feeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407027/oracle-replace-function-isnt-handling-carriage-returns-line-feeds)

Answer (score 0):

Update your value to have a line feed character before the carriage return character.

So if you have the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( value VARCHAR2(20) );
INSERT INTO test_data ( value ) VALUES ( 'This
That' );
```

Then you can insert the LF before the CR:

```sql
UPDATE test_data
SET    value = REPLACE( value, CHR(10), CHR(13) || CHR(10) )
WHERE  INSTR( value, CHR(10) ) > 0
```

Then your query:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR( value, 1, 7 ) FROM test_data;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | SUBSTR(VALUE,1,7) |
> | :---------------- |
> | This              |
> | T                 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=412db7b6863ddf1c23c20cd843755d34)*